# Concatenate result of group by into string

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables

```
Patients{
    Id
}

PatientsDoctorAssociation{
    PatientId,
    DoctorId
}
```

Using LINQ-to-Entities I want to make a group by of the join of this 2 tables, and I would like to concatenate the DoctorId into a single string, like this:

```
list = (from a in db.Patients
        join b in db.PatientsDoctorAssociation on a.Id equals b.PatientId
        group new {A=a,B=b} by b.PatientId into g
        select new {
            PatientId = g.Key,
            DoctorIds = ??
        });
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: There is no need to create a new object.  I think you should just be able to join table `a` with table `b` and then select b after you join on the PatientID

Comment: Take a look at `string.Join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx).

The catch is, that is cannot be translated to SQL. Therefore you need to do that in-memory, after you have retrieved the query-result. You can use the [`.AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that.

```
var list = (from a in db.Patients
            join b in db.PatientsDoctorAssociation on a.Id equals b.PatientId
            group new { A = a, B = b } by b.PatientId
            into g
            select new
            {
                PatientId = g.Key,
                DoctorIds = g.Select(z => z.B.DoctorId)
            }
    )
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        PatientId = x.PatientId,
        DoctorIds = string.Join(",", x.DoctorIds)
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

[string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the trick.

```
DoctorIds = string.Join(",", g.Select(p=>p.B.DoctorId))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var list = (from a in db.Patients
join b in db.PatientsDoctorAssociation on a.Id equals b.PatientId
select b).toList();
```

That gets you the PatientId as well as the DoctorID based on your join.

If you mean string manipulation, can we see the format of your doctor names?